# r.js and the text plugin

Tags: require, r.js

I am trying to compile a project that is making use of require.js. I would like to optmize with r.js but i face a build problem :

```
Error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
In module tree:
    main
      vorbok
        dataloader
```

I have notice in the dataload module that if i take this line, the problem is gone :

```
"text!/templates/registration/mous
```

tache/toppanel.moustache"

My configuration file is :

```
({
    appDir: "../../lambdev/src/interface/static/js/registration",
    baseUrl: ".",
    dir: "../app-build",
    paths: {
        jquery: '../jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min',
        Grid:"grid",
        Backbone:"../bower_components/backbone/backbone-min",
        Gridutils:"gridutils",
        Underscore:"../bower_components/underscore/underscore-min",
        text:"../bower_components/requirejs-text/text",
        mustache:"../mustache",
        jcolor: "jquery/jquery.color",
        bootstrap:"../bootstrap3/bootstrap.min",
        gridtable:"gridtable",
        gridvalidation:"gridvalidation",
        table_engine:"table_engine",
        paginator:'../bootstrap3/bootstrap-paginator.min',
        fangskraningpanel:"mmode/massaskraning",
        routerfunctions:"routerfunctions",
        moment:"../bower_components/moment/min/moment.min",
        rowvalidation:"rowvalidation",
        utils:"../various/utils",
        batch:"batch",
        messages:"messages",  
        autocomplete:"../bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min",
        jstorage:"../bower_components/jstorage/jstorage.min",   
        notify:"notify",
        whenitype:"../bower_components/jquery.whenitype/dist/jquery.whenitype.min",
        dataloader:"dataloader",
        inputhelper:"../various/input.helper",
        listeners:"listeners",   
        nod:"../bower_components/jquery-nod/nod",
        tooltip:"bootstrap3/tooltip",
        qtip:"../jquery/jquery.qtip",
        modal:"../bootstrap3/modal",  
        ramsearch:"../various/ramsearch",
        ewesearch:"../various/ewesearch",
        focusmanager:"focusmanager",
        vorbok:"mmode/vorbok",
        afdrifaskraning:"mmode/afdrifaskraning",
        saedingaskraning:"mmode/saedingaskraning",
        saedingar:"mmode/saedingar",
        error_check_panel:"mmode/error_check_panel",
        keytooltips:"keytooltips",


    },
    optimizeCss: "standard.keepLines",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main"
        }
    ],
    stubModules : ['text'],
    inlineText: true,
    optimizeAllPluginResources: false,
    fileExclusionRegExp: /\.hg/
})
```

I would need to know how I can fix the error due to the text plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an old question, it seems, but I just ran into and resolved this issue myself, so I thought I'd reach out.

For me, the define path for my text file wasn't to RequireJS's tastes. I had my HTML templates in my file system separated from my JS files, as below:

```
.
├── html
|   ├── ko-component-template.html
├── js
|   ├── app
|       ├── ko-component.js
```

So I was defining the HTML template like so:

```
'text!../../html/ko-component-template.html'
```

That worked without compiling RequireJS, but once Grunt compiled it, that's when the error popped up.

So I reorganized it so I wouldn't have to traverse up into parent directories

```
.
├── js
|   ├── app
|       ├── ko-component.js
|   ├── html
|       ├── ko-component-template.html
```

And now I can define the HTML template like this:

```
'text!html/ko-component-template.html'
```